# How To Compact a Realm Using Realm JS

Tags: realm, realm-js

I want to compact a Realm file in my Node JS app, but there is nothing about it in the [Realm JS docs](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/#realms).

I dug into the [JS API reference](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/api/Realm.html#compact), but the usage is vague (at least to me).

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
//This is my own custom function
function compactRealmFile(path){
  return Realm.open({ path: path }).then(realm => {
    if(realm.compact()){
      //-- Successful compaction --
      return Promise.resolve()
    }else{
      return Promise.reject('Compaction error!')
    }
  })
  .catch(error => {
    return Promise.reject('Realm compaction error: '+error)
  })
}
```

Does this even work? Does it just overwrite the existing realm file to be compacted?